# Custom Type Converter (AutoMapper) and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have used the following guide to setup AutoMapper with my .NET Core Web App (DI): https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/

It all works fine and dandy - until I want to use a custom type converter. I have made the following:

```
public class TimeSpanConverter : ITypeConverter<string, TimeSpan>
{
    public TimeSpan Convert(string source, TimeSpan destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return TimeSpan.Parse(source);
    }
}
```

And then using the new converter with:

```
CreateMap<string, TimeSpan>().ConvertUsing(new TimeSpanConverter());
```

Problem is that it does not get called! I have tried moving it outside the project to a simple console application with no DI and it works fine there, so it must be something with how it is setup. Have trawled through numerous guides, but I end up at a blank.

My mapping profile is this:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        // Add as many of these lines as you need to map your objects
        CreateMap<string, TimeSpan>().ConvertUsing(new TimeSpanConverter());
        CreateMap<Channel, ChannelDto>();
        CreateMap<Location, LocationDto>();
        CreateMap<LocationDto, Location>();
        CreateMap<OperatingSchedule, OperatingScheduleDto>();
        CreateMap<OperatingSchedule, AddOperatingScheduleRequest>();
        CreateMap<AddOperatingScheduleRequest, OperatingSchedule>();
    }

    public class TimeSpanConverter : ITypeConverter<string, TimeSpan>
    {
        public TimeSpan Convert(string source, TimeSpan destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return TimeSpan.Parse(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Under ConfigureServices i have:

```
services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
services.AddTransient<ITypeConverter<string, TimeSpan>, TimeSpanConverter>();
services.AddTransient<IConfigurationRepository, ConfigurationRepositorySql>();
services.AddTransient<IDataStoreRepository, DataStoreRepositoryInflux>();
services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();
services.AddMvc();
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I already have that and AutoMapper works in my project - just not with Custom Converters

Comment: No, you don't :)

Comment: hmmm i might see what you mean...so basically this is what i am missing?
- As a singleton for the MapperConfiguration
and
- As a scoped instance for IMapper ?

Comment: I don't know about that one, but clearly you're not passing anything to AddAutoMapper. And you register the type converter for no reason. You might want to check out the tests, because your code looks different.

Comment: I'm quite unsure what to pass to AddAutoMapper as per the link you sent. They guide I used to begin with doesnt mention paramters to this method? What would go there?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
Turns out everything was indeed working and setup as it should be according to the first guide. I had a typo in the properties which caused it not to map. 
Note to self: Be very diligent with naming...

Comment: That's why AssertConfigurationIsValid exists.